# Creating fixed position text as the page scrolls down then stop a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an effect basically exactly the same as the one used on this page: http://www.ohmy.io/work/landrover-live/

When you scroll down the page the text moves with the scroll and then stops at a certain position.

Can anyone direct to how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) what you are looking for?

Comment: Look up parallax scrolling

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
.some-class{
  position: sticky;
  top: //now used to set position to stick to
  left: //or you could sticky left, etc.
}
```

[CSS Position](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fposition&ei=VtiFVelxiOOgBOPxl8AC&usg=AFQjCNHPzjf_2VeL9tMO41LT7lqJfPDNpA&sig2=71FjwXg0L6cl93vHdWRN1g&bvm=bv.96339352,d.cGU)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is switch between classes when you hit the bottom of the page, or location of some element...

This is an example, it can be made better I'm sure

Html:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    //this is for normal window:
    //   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    //this is for this test:
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>100){
        $(".stuck").addClass("release").removeClass("stuck");
    }
});
```

```css
.stuck{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

.release{
    position: relative;
    top: 320px;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

.main{
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
}
.left{
    margin-top: 300px;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.right{
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="right stuck">
        here i am
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        will you send me an angel
    </div>
</div>
```

or fiddle if you pref: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b42nw946/7/)